# Tricky performance problem about UIButton's in UITableViewCell (iPhone)

Tags: iphone, uitableview, uiscrollview, grid, photo

I'm going to implement a view similar to the original photo app in iOS.

I created a customized UITableViewCell which has 4 UIButton in it. And it updates the button's image when the image array of the cell changed.

I worked hard to get the performance really satisfying. However, I found a tricky lag problem about it.

When I use my app normally, the scrolling is very smooth without significant lag. But if I keep the app (simulator) running on the "thumbnail grid view", and switch to other applications in Mac OS. After a while (maybe about 1 minute), when I switch back to the simulator, the scroll view gets stuck. It's hard to scroll it. If I click on something switching to another view and then switch back, everything is smooth again. So tricky.

I also tried the [`TTRemoteExamples`](https://github.com/klazuka/TTRemoteExamples) which uses `three20` to implement the grid view. It also gets stuck after switching between different applications in Mac OS (not in the iOS).

Then I tried not filling the customized cell with UIButton but 4 images. It didn't get stuck. So maybe the reason lies in the conflict between UITableViewCell and UIButton?

I don't know if it only happens on simulator or have potential performance problem when shipped to device (I haven't got the device to test on).

Apple's photo app will never be like this.

So I'm going to implement it from UIScrollView by myself to see if the problem is caused by the UITableView's mechanism. I still want to know the reason for the lag if anyone has come to it and solved it.

Sorry for my poor English, I hope you can catch my meaning.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Referring to `Subclassing UITableViewCell` section in `Table View Programming Guide for iOS`,
I finally solved the problem by implementing my custom mimicking the way from the guide, without adding subviews to `UITableViewCell`.

Apparently, adding too many subviews, only 4 in my code although, caused the strange problem I mentioned above. So, **NEVER ADD SUBVIEWS**, especially those with UIImageView's in it, to the contentView of `UITableViewCell` or `UITableViewCell` itself.

Instead, keep data's in the customized `UITableViewCell`, and do every drawing related thing in `drawRect`, using `-[UIImage drawAtPoint:]` and `-[NSString drawAtPoint:withFont:]`.

In fact, the Apple's guide has mentioned it. It's careless of me skimming the part.

However, I'm still curious about why, as I mentioned, it only occurs when you switch between applications in your Mac OS, not iOS. I don't know the reason indeed.

Comment: What's more, catch touch event in `touchesBegan:withEvent:`, and figure out which `grid` was pressed by calculation with `[event locationInView:theView]`.

Comment: Actually, custom drawing isn't required so long as you aren't trying to add non-opaque subviews. If you add subviews that are opaque, many of the performance issues are greatly minimized.

Comment: Yep, I do set all the subviews as opaque, the performance is not bad. The problem I met is hard to describe as it's not always there. Maybe you can run the `TTRemoteExamples` I mentioned and try to do what I said (stay in `grid list of image` view, then switch between simulator and other applications, wait some seconds before switching back). Then maybe the lag will occur.

Answer (score 2):

Who cares what the simulator does, seriously. Let it fart magical evil fairies that hijack the world's financial system causing it to enter a world of collapse...oh wait, maybe it already did that.

Seriously though, look at using code like [AQGridView](https://github.com/AlanQuatermain/AQGridView). It's very stable, provides an interface very much like a tableview, and is used in many projects. You also avoid the nonsense that is Three20 going this route. It's win-win.

But remember, always, and I do mean always, care what your app does on a device, if it isn't doing the same thing on the simulator, don't worry about it, you shouldn't be testing on the sim 99% of the time anyway. Users interact with your app on their devices, not your simulator. :)

Comment: Thanks for replying. In fact, I'm not doing horizontal scrolling. I'm implementing the `grid view` like the `photo list` view in the photo app, but not the horizontal scrolling enabled one-photo view.